# Genitive of time with or without an article, "Morgens" vs. "eines Tages"

Tags: noun, genitive

The question is on the instances of "genitive of time" found in this passage from a translation Albert Camus's The Stranger (by Uli Aumüller)

> Auf meinem Tisch stapelte sich ein Haufen Seefrachtbriefe, und ich mußte sie alle durchsehen. Bevor ich das Büro verließ, um essen zu gehen, habe ich mir die Hände gewaschen. **Mittags** mag ich diesen Augenblick sehr. **Abends** macht er mir weniger Spaß, weil das Rollhandtuch, das man dabei gebraucht, ganz feucht ist: es ist den ganzen Tag benutzt worden. Ich habe meinen Chef **eines Tages** darauf hingewiesen. Er hat geantwortet, er fände das bedauerlich, aber es wäre doch eine belanglose Nebensache.

It seems to me that, as used above:

- *Mittags* and *Abends* refer to a typical afternoon and evening, or most afternoons and evenings.  (Accordingly, *mag* and *macht* refer to a tendency.)
- *eines Tages* refers to a particular day.  (*habe hingewiesen* refers to a particular action.)

Let us call this the pattern.

**QUESTION**

Which of the following is the case?

1. The pattern always holds true.  This means:

   - genitive of time without an article (e.g. *Mittags*) always refers to a typical instance of time in question (be it day, morning or season) and
   - genitive of time with an indefinite article (e.g. *eines Tages*) always refers to a particular time.
2. The pattern does *not* always hold true.  Meaning:

   - genitive of time without an article *can* refer to a particular time and
   - genitive of time with an indefinite article *can* refer to a typical time.

If 2, please give some examples of genitive of time that is off-pattern.

To avoid any confusion, I am excluding genitive that qualifies a noun as in *am Mittag eines schönen Tages*. The question is on the genitive absolute construction only.

**BACKGROUND**

This background is not part of the question.

According to the Our Living Language section of this [Web page](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/of+a+morning), the *of a morning* construction is "not used for single actions."  If true, that makes English rather different from German in this respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mittags is not genitive, but an adverbial form of *Mittag*. This means every *Mittag.* The same holds for *Abend* and *abends*. Transforming

> Mittags mag ich diesen Augenblick sehr.

would lead to

> Diesen Augenblick mag ich **mittags** sehr.  (und nicht *Mittags*)

although it's not the same intended style. Hence, to answer your question, neither 1 nor 2 hold exactly in their original form, but,  indeed, the  genitive in *eines Tages* usually refers to a particular time and the adverbs like *morgens, montags, abends* refer to recurrent events.

Comment: agree with "mittags" is not genitive (any more), but rather an adverb. It used to be, though: An archaic form would be "Des Morgens", which I really consider genitive - Has also found its way into literature: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Des_Morgens

Comment: "Eine Art Genitivus absolutus kommt auch im Deutschen vor. Beispiele: klopfenden Herzens, unverrichteter Dinge." https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genitivus_absolutus