# The adverb "abends" as a reference to a particular evening

Tags: adverb

I understand that expressions such as *morgens* and *abends* are adverbs referring to all, most or typical instances of the time in question.  So if someone is said to take a walk *morgens*, I should understand that this is part of his morning routine.  On thus far, see [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33841/7629) to another post.

But I seem to have found a contrary usage in this passage from a translation of Camus's The Stranger (by Georg Goyert and Hans Georg Brenner).

> Schweißgebadet kamen wir bei Celeste an. Wie immer war er da, mit dickem Bauch, Schürze und weißem Schnurrbart. Er fragte mich, ob es mir einigermaßen ginge. Ich bejahte und sagte, daß ich Hunger hätte. Ich aß sehr schnell und trank eine Tasse Kaffee. Dann ging ich nach Hause, schlief ein bißchen, weil ich zuviel Wein getrunken hatte, und als ich wach wurde, hatte ich Lust auf eine Zigarette. Es war spät, und ich mußte laufen, um die Tram noch zu erwischen. Ich arbeitete den ganzen Nachmittag. Es war im Büro sehr heiß, und als ich **abends** nach Hause ging, freute ich mich, langsam über die Kais gehen zu können. Der Himmel war grün, und ich fühlte mich wohl. Trotzdem ging ich direkt nach Hause, weil ich mir zum Abendbrot Bratkartoffeln machen wollte.

Because the whole paragraph is on what happened on this particular day, I want to read *abends* as a reference to a particular evening (and the clause as referring to the joy of walking on the quay as the narrator went home that evening).

**QUESTION**

How should I understand *abends* in the passage?

For example:

1. The suggestion of routine in *abends* is so strong that I have no choice but to read it as referring to a typical evening.
2. *abends* is an awkward choice for the passage, but can accommodate a reference to a particular evening.  (If this is the case, please let me know what would not have been awkward at all.  E.g. *am Abend*?)
3. *abends* does a fine job referring to a particular evening when context demands it.  No awkwardness.

**BACKGROUND**

*abends* occurs in another translation (by Uli Aumüller).  So one could ask the same thing about that.

> Wir sind in Schweiß gebadet bei Céleste angekommen. Er war immer noch da, mit seinem dicken Bauch, seiner Schürze und seinem weißen Schnurrbart. Er hat mich gefragt, ob «es trotzdem gutginge». Ich habe ja gesagt und daß ich Hunger hätte. Ich habe sehr schnell gegessen und habe einen Kaffee getrunken. Dann bin ich nach Hause gegangen, habe ein bißchen geschlafen, weil ich zuviel Wein getrunken hatte, und als ich aufwachte, habe ich Lust gehabt zu rauchen. Es war spät, und ich bin gelaufen, um eine Straßenbahn zu erwischen. Ich habe den ganzen Nachmittag gearbeitet. Es war sehr heiß im Büro, und **abends**, beim Weggehen, war ich froh, langsam über die Kais zurückzuschlendern. Der Himmel war grün, ich fühlte mich wohl. Trotzdem bin ich direkt nach Hause gegangen, weil ich mir Kartoffeln kochen wollte.

I am not suggesting that the French original is relevant to our question.  But if anyone wants to see it:

> Nous sommes arrivés en nage chez Céleste. Il était toujours là, avec son gros ventre, son tablier et ses moustaches blanches. Il m’a demandé si « ça allait quand même ». Je lui ai dit que oui et que j’avais faim. J’ai mangé très vite et j’ai pris du café. Puis je suis rentré chez moi, j’ai dormi un peu parce que j’avais trop bu de vin et, en me réveillant, j’ai eu envie de fumer. Il était tard et j’ai couru pour attraper un tram. J’ai travaillé tout l’après-midi. Il faisait très chaud dans le bureau et **le soir**, en sortant, j’ai été heureux de revenir en marchant lentement le long des quais. Le ciel était vert, je me sentais content. Tout de même, je suis rentré directement chez moi parce que je voulais me préparer des pommes de terre bouillies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's

> 3. *abends* does a fine job referring to a particular evening when context demands it. No awkwardness.

You also could use *morgens* or *mittags* in similar settings:

> Gestern war ein sehr ungewöhnlicher Tag. Es war alles anders als sonst. Das fing schon an, als ich **morgens** aufstehen wollte: Als ich meine Beine aus dem Bett schwingen wollte, knallte ich gegen eine Wand. Es war nicht mein Bett in dem ich lag, ich lag in irgend einem fremden Bett. Nur, in welchem?
>
> Als ich **mittags** vom Schreibtisch aufstand, klingelte das Telefon. Es war Gruber. Gruber rief mich sonst nie im Büro an, ich wusste gar nicht, dass ich ihm meine Büro-Nummer gegeben hatte.

In both examples I was using *morgens/mittags* to refer to one particular morning/noon. This is absolutely ok and good style. Nothing wrong with it.

The word »abends« just means: "in the evening". Depending on context, this can be every evening, or just one certain evening. This is also true for »morgens« and »mittags« (but not for »montags, dienstags, ...«).

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking this. German speakers are very sloppy about current and recurrent events.

What you mean with **abends** or **am Abend** is simply *not defined* unless you add words as *heute*, *morgen*, *einmal*, *immer*, *wieder* etc.

> Am Abend sehe ich fern. (not defined)
>
> Abends sehe ich fern. (not defined)
>
> Heute Abend sehe ich fern. (I am talking about today.)
>
> Abends sehe ich immer fern. (I am talking about every day.)